# Delphi xe8 error reading textfile created from Delphi 7 version and vice versa

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe8

I try to convert a code from Delphi 7 to delphi xe8 and I cannot find a solution to the following case.

Our old application creates a txt file which first row is like that

±HEADER―ID°N1799―USER_ID°N1―PATH_NAME―R_DATABASE°TC:\DATA―R_SERVER°TTEST_SRV―R_COMPUTER°TMYPC―

Char(―) is chr(175).

We tried to read the already created file from our new application with Delphi xe8 like that:

```
  StrData := TStringList.Create;
  StrData.LoadFromFile(sFile);
```

StrData.Text returns the desired text but chr(175) is replaced with chr(8213).

In order to go on I did the followings:

```
  StrData.LoadFromFile(sFile,TEncoding.ANSI);  
  StrData.Text := StringReplace(StrData.Text,Chr(8213),Chr(175),[rfReplaceAll]);
```

What I cannot solve is the opposite case.

I have to create that file from Delphi xe8 so as it would be exactly the same with the one produced from the old delphi 7 application.

At the beginning I used the same code we had:

```
StrData.SavetoFile(sFile); //returns text but chr(175) is replaced with (?)
```

Also i tried all encodings with no results.

```
StrData.SavetoFile(sFile,Ansi);//returns text but chr(175) is replaced with (?) etc.
```

The same results also when converts the code to TStreamFile or textfile.

base64 encode files

Old one - Correct one (StrData.SavetoFile(sFile)) //Delphi 7

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

StrData.SavetoFile(sFile,Tencoding.Ansi); & StrData.SavetoFile(sFile); //XE8

wrFIRUFERVI/SUTCsE4xODY3P1JJRMKwTjM2Mj9DU0lURV9JRMKwTjE/UlNJVEVfSUTCsE4xMDE/U1NJVEVfSUTCsE4xP1RSTl9EQVRFwrBENDIzODIuNzA3NzA4MzMzMz9VU0VSX0lEwrBOMT9QQVRIX05BTUXCsFRcXGRlbHBoaTIwMTJyMlxCRU5FRklUX1RFU1RcUEFfT0ZGSUNFX1ZTTFxUUkFOU0ZFUlxFWFBPUlQ/RklMRV9OQU1FwrBUQU5BRDM2Mk0udHh0P0ZJTEVfVFlQRcKwTj9QQ0tfU0VOREVSwrBUQWRtaW4/UENLX05PVEVTwrBOP19SVl9JRDHCsE4/U1ZfSUTCsE4/UlZfSUTCsE4/UkRCX0lEwrBOMTE/U0RCX0lEwrBOMTE/UENLX0NOWFTCsFQwMywxNSw3MiwwMD9LRVlJRMKwVHtGQzM1N0QyNC1EQjRBLTRBOUMtQkE3My0xQ0FBMEVFRDUzOUJ9P0ZMX1RZUEXCsE4yP0ZMX1NUQVRVU8KwTjA/U1RBUlRfRFTCsEQ0MjM4Mi43MDcyNjg1MTg1P1JfU1RBUlRfRFTCsEQ/Ul9FTkRfRFTCsEQ/Ul9VU0VSwrBUP1JfUEFUSMKwVD9TSVpFX1BDS8KwTj9TSVpFX0RBVEHCsE4/U0laRV9BVENIwrBOP1NJWkVfRE9DU8KwTj9EQVRFX0lOwrBEP1JfREFUQUJBU0XCsFQ/Ul9TRVJWRVLCsFQ/Ul9DT01QVVRFUsKwVD8=

StrData.SavetoFile(sFile,Tencoding.UTF8); //XE8

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

Any ideas?

Comment: This doesn't ring true. Please can you base64 encode your text file, edit it into the question and let us have a look at it.

Comment: @ David Heffernan sorry but I didn't understand what exactly you want me to do. Could you be more specific please?

Comment: Seems simple enough. Whatever text file you have, run it through a Base64 encoder, and share the result here in your question.

Comment: @ Ken White in my case 'E' and 'R' can be any character. It seems difficult to me to replace this character in that way. By the way this character is created from code with chr(175).

Comment: We'd like to see the actual file. What you describe does not hang together. You've described your file. We can help property if we can see the actual file. If you base64 encode it we'll know we have the exact same file. The call to `StringReplace` is clearly wrong.

Comment: Could you put this file (or it's beginning) to some file exchange server to examine binary contents?

Comment: @MBo Then the link will go stale. Base64 encoded and it will last forever.

Comment: @David Heffernan It is not clear for me yet - whether author can change old application.

Comment: @MBo The question is about code in XE8, so the assumption is that the old program is fixed.

Comment: @MBo no I cannot change the old application. That's the problem.

Comment: I see that binary data are (65001) UTF-8 coded

Answer (score 3):

The file saved by your Delphi 7 program is UTF-8 encoded. I decoded the base64 that you supplied and look at it in a hex editor. It looks like this:

[image]

The first two bytes are `C2 B1`. That is the UTF-8 encoding for ±. You can check that here: https://mothereff.in/utf-8.

Use `LoadFromFile(..., TEncoding.UTF8)` to load the file, and `SaveToFile(..., TEncoding.UTF8)` to save it. That's all you need to do. Note that when you save this way then a BOM will be included in the file. If that is not desired then it possible to omit the BOM, as has been covered here before.

Do note that you must remove the call to `StringReplace`. That modifies the text and serves no useful purpose. You absolutely do not wish to replace [U+2015](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2015/index.htm) ― with [U+00AF](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00af/index.htm) ¯.

Based on the comments to this answer it seems that you have some Delphi 7 code that produced UTF-8 encoded text which behaves incorrectly when executed by Delphi XE8. That's not surprising due to the change from ANSI to UTF-16. You will need to revisit this code and adapt it appropriately. It's impossible for us to say more given the fact the only you have this code.

It feels very much as though you are trying things almost at random and hoping for a quick fix. That is not productive. You will only make progress with a clear understanding of Unicode, and your program. You will need to step back, slow down, and fill in the gaps in your knowledge.

Comment: SaveToFile(..., TEncoding.UTF8) results to the third file encoded which is not the same with the first one.

Comment: Works fine here. The only difference is that when you save using `TEncoding.UTF8` you'll get a BOM and your original file did not have a BOM. Anyway, I've decoded the files and shown you what the encoding is. I think the next step is for you to take that knowledge and make sure you fully understand what is going on. The nitty gritty details of your actual program is not something that we can help you with.

Comment: Looking at that third file in your question, that is the result of your code that still uses `StringReplace` to modify the contents. Read the final paragraph in my answer please.

Comment: No it isn't. I have used replace only on loading procedure. The create procedure is completely different and the file is new not modified)

Comment: Starting from the first base64 encoded file, I decoded it to binary. I observed that it was UTF-8 encoded. I then loaded and saved using `TEncoding.UTF8` and the contents were identical, apart from the saved file having a BOM at the front. You can do the same yourself to convince yourself that I am right. As I read that latest comment of yours you are still calling `StringReplace`. Why?

Comment: Now, if you have code that generates the file from scratch, then I guess there is a problem with that code. Perhaps you are writing code like `chr(175)` which previously would have been an ANSI character, and is now a different Unicode character. If you do have code to create the file, then the problem will presumably be found there. We cannot see it. You now know that the file you are creating is meant to be UTF-8 encoded. Probably the cleanest way forward is to change the code to use UTF-16 code points, and then `TEncoding.UTF8` when writing.

Comment: Another route would be to build your text as encoded UTF-8 as you currently do. But you'd have to stop using strings and string lists since they are UTF-16 encoded. You could use a UTF8 encoded type, or perhaps even a byte array. Lots of ways to solve the problem, but that's really on you. We can't advise you on your code that we can't see. You definitely need to do some revision on Unicode, encodings, and how they are handled in Delphi because your understanding is still somewhat shaky. Good luck.

Comment: when I call loadfromfile(sfile,tencoding.utf8) I get the following message: No mapping for the unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page. That's why I had used the replace.

Comment: I'll repeat what I said above. I took your first base64 encoded file, and decoded it to binary bytes which I put on disk. I then loaded with LoadFromFile(..., TEncoding.UTF8). This succeeded and gave text starting ±HEADER―ID°. If you do the same, you will observe the same. What more do you want from us?

Comment: @ David Heffernan I used that site encoder https://www.base64encode.org/ propably this is the problem. I will try to do it with a more secure one. Thank you for your help .

Comment: The problem is that you don't have a strong grasp of Unicode, or what your program does. For instance, did you base64 encode the file, or did you paste text into a window? Anyway, until you have more understanding you are wasting your time. Stop guessing. Stop using trial and error. Take some time to learn.

Comment: @P.A I second David's advice. The program consists of stages, that transform data and pass it to the next one. You have to inspect the data between the stages to find the exact stage that makes it wrong. Then you would be able to spot the mistake or to "divide et empera" the faulty stage into substages and again find the faulty piece. What you do now, trying almost random guesses and pulling almost random handles, can only lead you to combinatorial explosion. If it did not worked in the first hour or two - chances it would randomly start to work next hour are infinitesimal. Time to analyze.